# BonitaBPM: Connecting to a Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, bonita

I'm extremely new when it comes to Bonita BPM and I am having troubles connecting to my MySQL database.

I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.bpm.connector.ConnectorExecutionException: USERNAME=install | org.bonitasoft.engine.core.operation.exception.SOperationExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.expression.exception.SExpressionEvaluationException: No value found for mandatory expression 'singleResult' of type Input Expression

I was hoping someone had a bit more experience with this stuff than I do. I've looked around the web but can't find any tutorials for the current version (7.3).

**Setup Information:**

```
Driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstdatabase
username:root
password:*******
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE test_id = 'testingquery';
```

`testing` is a table in `firstdatabase` with one entry and one column. The column is `test_id` and the one entry is `testingquery`.

Comment: Bob , looks like http://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/no-graphic-mode-oracle-connector already has a solution. Not sure if this was tried

Comment: Issue is most likely to be in the way you process the output of the connector. In order to help it would be great if you can share your process .bos file (using "Export" menu of Bonita BPM Studio).